# Load .properties file depends on http host

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I need to hold a css class names in property file and change them depending on current http host. Could you help me, how to load .properties file during each http request (not spring context initialization). Also, may be you know much more good solution for that. Thanks!

Comment: That is what Springs theming support is for. Instead of reinventing the wheel just use that. Create your own `ThemeResolver` which retrieves the theme to use for the current request, register it in the context and use springs theming support to load the appropriate css file. (Your classnames shouldn't really change only the css files loaded).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a certain list of hosts make a map of hostname and properties, e.g.         Map< String, Properties>.
If you're choosing properties based on some matching logic, make a matcher that simple choose one of the preloaded properties. ( new Properties().load(myFileReader) )
PS: loading properties from disk on each http request is not a good idea.